# Hiding content after choosing the right JS function

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Background:** I have different categories on my website (one category per page). These categories are divided into various Tables and JavaScript functions.

**Now to my problem:** I would like to hide all other HTML tables if I click in a checkbox from one table (this enables the JS function). I am already working with the CSS hide function, but cannot achieve the desired result with it because everything is hidden by default.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve the problem? The emergency plan would be to give each table its own page, but that would mean a lot more effort in the php files... Many thanks in advance!

The code:

```js
document.getElementById("listForm").addEventListener("input", function() {
  const checkedCount = this.querySelectorAll(".choice:checked").length
  if (checkedCount > 2 || this.querySelector('input#cbg').checked) {
    document.getElementById("showwhen2").className = "hide";
    document.getElementById("showwhen3").className = "nonhide";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("showwhen3").className = "hide";
    document.getElementById("showwhen2").className = "nonhide";
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = checkedCount;
});

document.getElementById("listForm2").addEventListener("input", function() {
  const checkedCount2 = this.querySelectorAll(".choice:checked").length
  if (checkedCount2 > 2 || this.querySelector('input#cbg2').checked) {
    document.getElementById("showwhen22").className = "hide";
    document.getElementById("showwhen32").className = "nonhide";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("showwhen32").className = "hide";
    document.getElementById("showwhen22").className = "nonhide";
  }
  document.getElementById("total2").value = checkedCount2;
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="listForm">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="G">
        <td><b>G</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="choice" id="cbg" name="choiceG" value="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="A"><b>A</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="choice" name="choiceA" value="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="B"><b>B</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="choice" name="choiceB" value="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="C"><b>C</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="choice" name="choiceC" value="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" ;="" style="text-align:right;"><b>Sum:</b></td>
        <td><input disabled="" type="text" size="2" name="total" id="total" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
<form id="listForm2">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="G">
        <td><b>G</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="choice" id="cbg" name="choiceG" value="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="A"><b>A</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="choice" name="choiceA" value="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="B"><b>B</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="choice" name="choiceB" value="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="C"><b>C</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="choice" name="choiceC" value="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" ;="" style="text-align:right;"><b>Sum:</b></td>
        <td><input disabled="" type="text" size="2" name="total2" id="total2" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
<div id="showwhen2" class="hide">
  <p>1: 2 or less boxes checked; first box is unchecked</p>
</div>
<div id="showwhen3" class="hide">
  <p>1: first box or more than two boxes are checked</p>
</div>
<div id="showwhen22" class="hide">
  <p>2: 2 or less boxes checked; first box is unchecked</p>
</div>
<div id="showwhen32" class="hide">
  <p>2: first box or more than two boxes are checked</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to hide all tables but they are hidden by default. Could you explain?

Comment: Could you add a Codepen or show some HTML, CSS & JS so we can understand your setup?

Comment: I want to hide all tables, but not the one I cklick on. So at first all tables should not be hidden, the I click into one table and all the others should hide then. @Josh

Comment: So they are not hidden by default after all.  Then CSS hide should not be a problem.

Comment: The CSS hide works for the things I have done. But now I want to hide all the other tables not just the outcome. I thought I can do it with the hide function, but then i remembered that everything would be hidden by default if I do it like that. (I could make a box you have to cklick or something to change that but that would be ugly and I don't like that). @Josh

Comment: you could hide all tables with CSS except the one you clicked on. Simply set a CSS class on the Table you clicked and hide all tables without the class

Comment: Yes, i've done that but if u uncheck all checkboxes all tables are hidden and you have to reload the page @Josh

Comment: sorry I don't understand the question. What do you mean with "everything is hidden by default"?
If I run  your Code I can see every Table

Comment: "Hiding content after choosing the right JS function" could you please explain what "JS function" you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

I also added functionality to show the Tables again if no checkbox is checked.

```js
const allTables = document.querySelectorAll('.table-container');

function hideAllTablesExcept(table) {
    allTables.forEach(tableToHide => {
      if(tableToHide != table) {
        tableToHide.style.display = 'none';
      }
  });   
}

function showAllTables() {
    allTables.forEach(tableToHide => {
      tableToHide.style.display = 'block';
  });   
}

// this function will check if any checkbox in the given table is checked
function isTableUnused(table) {
    for (let checkbox of table.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')) {
        if(checkbox.checked) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
}

function calculateSum(table) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let checkbox of table.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')) {
    if(checkbox.checked) {
        sum += parseInt(checkbox.value);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

allTables.forEach(table => {
    const checkboxes = table.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        if(isTableUnused(table)) {
        showAllTables();
      } else {
        hideAllTablesExcept(table);
      }
      table.querySelector('.total').value = calculateSum(table);
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container red">
  <h1>Table 1</h1>
  <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>G</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>A</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>B</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>C</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>
    <span>Sum: </span>
    <input disabled="" type="text" size="2" class="total" value="0">
  </p>
</div>
  
<div class="table-container blue">
  <h1>Table 2</h1>
  <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>G</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>A</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>B</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>C</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>
    <span>Sum: </span>
    <input disabled="" type="text" size="2" class="total" value="0">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="table-container green">
  <h1>Table 3</h1>
  <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>G</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>A</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>B</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>C</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>
    <span>Sum: </span>
    <input disabled="" type="text" size="2" class="total" value="0">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="table-container orange">
  <h1>Table 4</h1>
  <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>G</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>A</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>B</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>C</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>
    <span>Sum: </span>
    <input disabled="" type="text" size="2" class="total" value="0">
  </p>
</div>
```